# How to frame a regex pattern if a word has to be followed y exactly one word?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in python-

```
x = "apple"
y = input('enter word')
```

here, if y is of the pattern- "apple.banana", i.e "apple." followed with exactly one word (be it any word) , then I have to perform an operation.
How do I set the regex pattern in python for this?
I went through quantifiers but none says "exactly one".

Comment: Because it is default. `a` means "one `a`". To match a whole string, wrap the pattern with `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: do you think - `print "ankush.rathi".startswith("ankush")` might be a simple solution to this ?

Comment: @AnkushRathi how does that guarantee `ankush` is followed by exactly one word?

Comment: @Austin oh yes, my bad. I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
import re

x = "apple"
y = input('enter word')

pattern = re.compile(r'{}\.\w+$'.format(x))
if pattern.match(y):
    print(True)
```

`\w+` matches one or more letters or digits. `$` matches the end of string.

Comment: Unnecessary to keep the compiled regex around, isn't it?

Comment: @CraigBrett unnecessary? I don't get you. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: You're initializing and keeping around a compiled regex named pattern, when you're (presumably) only checking the one string. If it's something that's going to be repeatedly used that's fine, but there's no indication that that is the case

Comment: Might be possible to do: re.compile(regex_here).match(y) or something, I don't know. All depends on the code around it and if this is a check that happens multiple times or not

Comment: @CraigBrett But I am pretty sure this question is from some sites like Hackerrank (possibly) where there is enough and more inputs to test for. Sure when there is no indication that favours either cases, let it stand as it is. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re

single = re.search('^\w+[\s\.]\w+$', x + ' ' + y)
print(single)
```

You can then run checks on if single is None or not

- \w matches any word (character) character
- + means 1 or more
- The stuff between the []s may appear only once
- \s matches a space
- . matches a dot (.). So either a space or a dot may go here
- ^ means at the start of the string
- $ means at the end

So you're saying, at the start of the string, you want 1 or more word characters, followed by either a single space or dot, then 1 or more word characters, then the end of the string.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, anonymous downvoter. Would you care to explain why you think this answer is unsuitable?

Comment: Sure, the op asked for a period, not a space. Also, I think y is the whole input to search. Not sure why you are concatenating. Also, when I downvoted there wasn't an explanation, just code.

Comment: Then care to explain what 'x' is for in the OP? I'd argue "follow" is ambiguous. However, I'll adapt it so it can work for either

Comment: Sounds good, removed the downvote. I took `x` to  be the first word you'd be searching for in the input rather than something to add to the input.

Comment: :) I'm blaming ambiguity here. My brain just turned follow into spaces for some reason without looking at the example. I still don't fully get the purpose of x. I think the OP will have to clarify